# How to merge different karma coverage html reports into single html file?

Tags: testcase, coverage

I am new to TDD. we have already executed the test cases through **karma-coverage.**. If the test case count increases, the code coverage took more time to complete the job. so i had switched into **concurrenlty** to implement the parallel test case execution. Before that, the code coverage results are generated as single html file. But now, i had configure the coverage results into separate folders to improve the performance on test cases.  But now, the coverage results are generated as separate html  report. But i want to combine these separate folder's index.html file into single html report.

so that, i have implemented the parallel execution of my repository using **"concurrently"**. I had configured the gulp  generate the separate code coverage reports for each folder. Each folder has set of **.spec file**  The gulp configuration details is given below,

**gulp zero:**

```
coverageReporter: {
        dir: './cireports',
        subdir: "codecoverage/zero",
        reporters: [
            { type: 'html', file: "UnitTestCover.html" },
        ]
    }
```

**gulp one:**

```
coverageReporter: {
        dir: './cireports',
        subdir: "codecoverage/one",
        reporters: [
            { type: 'html', file: "UnitTestCover.html" },
        ]
    }
```

**gulp two:**

```
coverageReporter: {
        dir: './cireports',
        subdir: "codecoverage/two",
        reporters: [
            { type: 'html', file: "UnitTestCover.html" },
        ]
    }
```

**gulp three:**

```
coverageReporter: {
        dir: './cireports',
        subdir: "codecoverage/three",
        reporters: [
            { type: 'html', file: "UnitTestCover.html" },
        ]
    }
```

If I executed following command through command prompt,

```
concurrently “gulp zero” “gulp one” “gulp two” “gulp three”
```

Test case was executed parallel and the coverage reports  generated in the specific folder. Each coverage folder has index.html file.  So I need to merge the coverage reports from all folders into single index.html file.

I had tried to merge the coverage reports from following package,  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat. So that I had installed the “gulp-concat” from following command,

```
npm install  --save -dev gulp-concat
```

After that, I had configure the gulp.js to merge the coverage reports, The gulp-concat configuration is given below,

**gulp-concat:**

```
gulp.task('merge', function () {
return gulp.src(['./cireports/codecoverage/zero/index.html', './cireports/codecoverage/one/index.html', './cireports/codecoverage/two/index.html', './cireports/codecoverage/three/index.html'])
  .pipe(concat('index.html'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

After test case execution completed, I had executed the “gulp merge” to merge the coverage reports. Expected output was not came. The merged index.html file was generated the series of coverage reports in a single index file

Can anyone tell me whether there is any plan to implement the merging of coverage reports?

Regards,

Thirunavukkarasu G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i had a found a solution to merge multiple coverage reports into single coverage object with istanbul-combine package.
 For Reference, refer the following link.[https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul-combine].

I had generated the coverage reporter output as json objects. After json coverage reports generated in the respective folder, I had merged them with istanbul-combine package. This package used for combining coverage reports from multiple objects into single html coverage report.

**My Solution is given below:-**

```
var combine = require('istanbul-combine');
.....
.....
.....
/**
* Generates html code coverage report in folder codecoverage/pack1
*/
gulp.task('generate_coverage1', function () {
     var opts = {
     dir: 'cireports/codecoverage/pack1',                       
     pattern: 'cireports/reporters/pack1/*.json',               
     print: 'none',                                            
     reporters: {
        html: {}
     }
};
combine.sync(opts);
});

/**
 * Generates html code coverage report in folder codecoverage/pack2
*/
gulp.task('generate_coverage2', function () {
    var opts = {
    dir: 'cireports/codecoverage/pack2',                       
    pattern: 'cireports/reporters/pack2/*.json',               
    print: 'none',                                           
    reporters: {
        html: {}
    }
};
combine.sync(opts);
});
```

Regards,

Creator